# Passing variable from ASP.net to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to pass a variable from asp.net to JavaScript?

Comment: What are you trying to do? An example could be helpful?

Comment: whichever method you use, remember to use `Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode` to encode your string to make it more secure.

Answer (score 34):

Create a property in your code behind

```
protected string MyProperty { get { return "your value"; } }
```

then in javascript

```
var myValue = "<%= MyProperty %>";
```

Comment: The security implications of this initialization pattern is being discussed here: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/265713/79604

Answer (score 19):

There are a number of ways:

1 - Write it out in your JavaScript with `<%= myVariable %>`
2 - Set a cookie server-side and then retrieve the cookie client side
3 - Set a hidden form input to your value
4 - Redirect to your page with the value as a querystring parameter, and then parse the params using JavaScript
5 - Build all your JavaScript server-side, save to a variable, and then write out the variable client-side.
6 - Retrieve the value with an AJAX request

Comment: The first option causes a `VBScript runtime error '800a000d' Type mismatch`... At least when the 'myVariable' is a recordset variable in a classic asp page, like `<%= rs("myVariable") %>`

Answer (score 9):

You can use an ASP.Net HiddenField. You just set its value on the server and retrieve it via javascript when you need it.

**Serverside**

```
hdf_Test.Value = "yourValue";
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdf_Test" />
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('hdf_Test').value
```

Comment: In the sever side this code doesn't work I tried string x; x.value="d"; it gives me error?

Comment: That is because you are trying to use a variable not a HiddenField control. I have updated my answer with more information.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use javascript tag

   ```
   <script>
       var var1 = @var1;  
       var var2 = @var2;  
   </script>
   ```
2. Use hidden field

   ```
   <input type="hidden" value="@var1" id="h_var1"/>  
   <input type="hidden" value="@var2" id="h_var2" />`
   ```

in js

```
$(function()
{
    var var1 = $("#h_var1").val();
    var var2 = $("#h_var2").val();
}
```

3.Retrieve data via ajax using json

```
var var1;
var var2;
    $.get(url,function(result)
    {
        var1 = result.var1; var2 = result.var2;
     }
```

@var syntax depend of your view engine. It maybe  `<%= Var1 %>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in your code behind:

public string json;

**you need to give it a value**

In your JavaScript you can enter:

```
<script>
    var myVar = <%=json%>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the string variable equivalent in your code side, this is code:

Example:

```
string jsString= JsEncoder.JavaScriptEncode("This is an example of C# string to be converted to javascript string",true));
```

Class Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace stackoverlofw.JavascriptEncoder
{
public class JsEncoder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Empty string for Java Script context
    /// </summary>
    private const string JavaScriptEmptyString = "''";


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes character Html encoding array
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly char[][] SafeListCodes = InitializeSafeList();



    /// <summary>
    /// Encodes input strings for use in JavaScript.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">String to be encoded.</param>
    /// <param name="emitQuotes">value indicating whether or not to emit quotes. true = emit quote. false = no quote.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Encoded string for use in JavaScript and does not return the output with en quotes.
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This function encodes all but known safe characters.  Characters are encoded using \xSINGLE_BYTE_HEX and \uDOUBLE_BYTE_HEX notation.
    /// <newpara/>
    /// Safe characters include:
    /// <list type="table">
    /// <item><term>a-z</term><description>Lower case alphabet</description></item>
    /// <item><term>A-Z</term><description>Upper case alphabet</description></item>
    /// <item><term>0-9</term><description>Numbers</description></item>
    /// <item><term>,</term><description>Comma</description></item>
    /// <item><term>.</term><description>Period</description></item>
    /// <item><term>-</term><description>Dash</description></item>
    /// <item><term>_</term><description>Underscore</description></item>
    /// <item><term> </term><description>Space</description></item>
    /// <item><term> </term><description>Other International character ranges</description></item>
    /// </list>
    /// <newpara/>
    /// Example inputs and encoded outputs:
    /// <list type="table">
    /// <item><term>alert('XSS Attack!');</term><description>'alert\x28\x27XSS Attack\x21\x27\x29\x3b'</description></item>
    /// <item><term>user@contoso.com</term><description>'user\x40contoso.com'</description></item>
    /// <item><term>Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library</term><description>'Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library'</description></item>
    /// </list>
    /// </remarks>
    public static string JavaScriptEncode(string input, bool emitQuotes)
    {
        // Input validation: empty or null string condition
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            return emitQuotes ? JavaScriptEmptyString : string.Empty;
        }

        // Use a new char array.
        int outputLength = 0;
        int inputLength = input.Length;
        char[] returnMe = new char[inputLength * 8]; // worst case length scenario

        // First step is to start the encoding with an apostrophe if flag is true.
        if (emitQuotes)
        {
            returnMe[outputLength++] = '\'';
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
        {
            int currentCharacterAsInteger = input[i];
            char currentCharacter = input[i];
            if (SafeListCodes[currentCharacterAsInteger] != null || currentCharacterAsInteger == 92 || (currentCharacterAsInteger >= 123 && currentCharacterAsInteger <= 127))
            {
                // character needs to be encoded
                if (currentCharacterAsInteger >= 127)
                {
                    returnMe[outputLength++] = '\\';
                    returnMe[outputLength++] = 'u';
                    string hex = ((int)currentCharacter).ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).PadLeft(4, '0');
                    returnMe[outputLength++] = hex[0];
                    returnMe[outputLength++] = hex[1];
                    returnMe[outputLength++] = hex[2];
                    returnMe[outputLength++] = hex[3];
                }
                else
                {
                    returnMe[outputLength++] = '\\';
                    returnMe[outputLength++] = 'x';
                    string hex = ((int)currentCharacter).ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).PadLeft(2, '0');
                    returnMe[outputLength++] = hex[0];
                    returnMe[outputLength++] = hex[1];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // character does not need encoding
                returnMe[outputLength++] = input[i];
            }
        }

        // Last step is to end the encoding with an apostrophe if flag is true.
        if (emitQuotes)
        {
            returnMe[outputLength++] = '\'';
        }

        return new string(returnMe, 0, outputLength);
    }




    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the safe list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A two dimensional character array containing characters and their encoded values.</returns>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Maintainability", "CA1502:AvoidExcessiveComplexity", Justification = "This is necessary complexity.")]
    private static char[][] InitializeSafeList()
    {
        char[][] allCharacters = new char[65536][];
        for (int i = 0; i < allCharacters.Length; i++)
        {
            if (
                (i >= 97 && i <= 122) ||        // a-z
                (i >= 65 && i <= 90) ||         // A-Z
                (i >= 48 && i <= 57) ||         // 0-9
                i == 32 ||                      // space
                i == 46 ||                      // .
                i == 44 ||                      // ,
                i == 45 ||                      // -
                i == 95 ||                      // _
                (i >= 256 && i <= 591) ||       // Latin,Extended-A,Latin Extended-B        
                (i >= 880 && i <= 2047) ||      // Greek and Coptic,Cyrillic,Cyrillic Supplement,Armenian,Hebrew,Arabic,Syriac,Arabic,Supplement,Thaana,NKo
                (i >= 2304 && i <= 6319) ||     // Devanagari,Bengali,Gurmukhi,Gujarati,Oriya,Tamil,Telugu,Kannada,Malayalam,Sinhala,Thai,Lao,Tibetan,Myanmar,eorgian,Hangul Jamo,Ethiopic,Ethiopic Supplement,Cherokee,Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics,Ogham,Runic,Tagalog,Hanunoo,Buhid,Tagbanwa,Khmer,Mongolian   
                (i >= 6400 && i <= 6687) ||     // Limbu, Tai Le, New Tai Lue, Khmer, Symbols, Buginese
                (i >= 6912 && i <= 7039) ||     // Balinese         
                (i >= 7680 && i <= 8191) ||     // Latin Extended Additional, Greek Extended        
                (i >= 11264 && i <= 11743) ||   // Glagolitic, Latin Extended-C, Coptic, Georgian Supplement, Tifinagh, Ethiopic Extended    
                (i >= 12352 && i <= 12591) ||   // Hiragana, Katakana, Bopomofo       
                (i >= 12688 && i <= 12735) ||   // Kanbun, Bopomofo Extended        
                (i >= 12784 && i <= 12799) ||   // Katakana, Phonetic Extensions         
                (i >= 19968 && i <= 40899) ||   // Mixed japanese/chinese/korean
                (i >= 40960 && i <= 42191) ||   // Yi Syllables, Yi Radicals        
                (i >= 42784 && i <= 43055) ||   // Latin Extended-D, Syloti, Nagri        
                (i >= 43072 && i <= 43135) ||   // Phags-pa         
                (i >= 44032 && i <= 55215) /* Hangul Syllables */)
            {
                allCharacters[i] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                string integerStringValue = i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                int integerStringLength = integerStringValue.Length;
                char[] thisChar = new char[integerStringLength];
                for (int j = 0; j < integerStringLength; j++)
                {
                    thisChar[j] = integerStringValue[j];
                }

                allCharacters[i] = thisChar;
            }
        }

        return allCharacters;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(<%=Greetings()%>);
</script>
```

In code behind:

```
protected string Greetings()
{
    return Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode("Hello World!");
}
```

[AntiXss Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/releases/view/80289)