# server side variable in javascript alert asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I want to access the server side variable in javascript alert.

```
 <asp:Button id="btnDelete" runat="server" class="deleteicon" Text='<%# Eval("iuser_id") %>' OnClick="deleteclick" onclientclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?'+<%# Eval("struser_name") %>);"/>
```

This is a delete button in a gridview. On click of it I want to alert the message and the user name. I am getting server tag is not formattted error.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing variable from ASP.net to JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540217/passing-variable-from-asp-net-to-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

Attach javascript click function in rowDataBound event of the gridview safest and easy way to do it...code is as below

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBond(object source, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
        { 
            Button btnAlertStatus = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnAlertStatus"); 

            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem; 

            string username = drv["User_name"].ToString(); 

            btnAlertStatus.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?"+ username + "')"); //error because of javascript left one bracket
        } 
    }
```

**PRE**

Try

JavaScript

```
function confirmMsg()
{

  var Variable = '<%= ServerVaraible %>';
  return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?'+ Variable );
}
```

HTML

```
 <asp:Button id="btnDelete" runat="server" class="deleteicon" Text='<%# Eval("iuser_id") %>' OnClick="deleteclick" onclientclick="return confirmMsg();"/>
```

Comment: but my button is in gridview and the struser_name is the binded value of the first column of the gridview

Comment: my onclientclick event is not firing the record is getting directly deleted without the alert. I change the onclick to onclientclick but still no luck

Comment: @asifa - check now i just forgot to include bracket in script ...now take the edit code again this will work..the line which i comment and resolue error by adding bracket..

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:Button id="btnDelete" runat="server" class="deleteicon" Text='<%# Eval("iuser_id") %>' OnClick="deleteclick" onclientclick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record? <%# Eval("struser_name") %>");'/>
```

Update. Try change quotes