# How to use Parameters passed to Partial view in a separate javascript file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a Partial view which takes in parameters and displays a Markdown Editor based on the parameters passed.

```
@Html.Partial("_MarkdownEditor", new { id = "fieldsection" })
<div id="@ViewData.Eval("id")"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var @ViewData.Eval("id") = new tui.Editor({
el: document.querySelector('#@ViewData.Eval("id")')})
</script>
```

In the source code of the tui.Editor i have a Ajax call to a controller something like this..

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'Home/Index',
          success: function (data) {
                  editor.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage'})
```

Here the problem is with this line..

```
editor.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage)
```

Here in the place of editor i need to reference the parameters passed to Partial view..it should be like this:

```
fieldcomments.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage)
```

It should be done dynamically i have tried something like..

```
{@ViewData.Eval("id")}.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage)
```

But this doesn't work like this? How can i reference the Parameters passed to Partial view in a separate javascript file??

Comment: Please more clarify you problem what you want to do.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI  `{@ViewData.Eval("id")}` contains the parameters passed to Partial view. I want to use those parameters here to `{@ViewData.Eval("id")}.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage)` But i am not able do that.! Is there a way to use the parameter passed to Partial view in Javascript file.?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the variable global in the view where you can still access `@ViewData.Eval("id")`. [Like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540381/5437903)

Example:

`<script> var a = @ViewData.Eval("id") </script>`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I have no problem in my view.  I wanted something like this.. `<%=@ViewData.Eval("id")%>.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage)`  . So when i pass parameters to Partial view for ex:`@Html.Partial("_MarkdownEditor", new { id = "fieldsection" })` it set `fieldcomments.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage)` Is there a way to achieve this?