# Pass a value to javascript from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to pass a value to javascript from code behind.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "<script type='text/javascript'>OpenPopUp();</script>", false);
```

JS:

```
function OpenPopUp(parameterValue) {           
        paramframe = parameterValue;            
        openmodal(paramframe);
    }
```

So `parameterValue` will have ID.Text value which is passed from code behind.

I need to pass a value from code behind in this function `OpenPopUp` to javascript.

I tried below code and the javascript doesn't fire. Am I passing the value correct to JS.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "<script type='text/javascript'>OpenPopUp(" + ID.Text + ");</script>", false);
```

`ID.Text` is a ItemTemplate value of a LinkButton in a gridview.

Comment: Do you have any console error in your browser?

Comment: Does it work without passing the parameter?

Comment: @erikscandola - I'm not getting any error. The JS function doesn't fire when I send the value.

Comment: @Haldo - It works fine without passing the parameter.

Comment: `ID.Text` instead of `text` (capital `T`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variable from ASP.net to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540217/passing-variable-from-asp-net-to-javascript)

Comment: Your making this a lot more [complicated than you need to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540274/542251)

Comment: @Learner I saw only a problem. If `OpenPopUp(" + ID.text + ");` will contains a text like `Hello Word`. So `OpenPopUp(Hello Word)` thrown an error. Try in this way: `OpenPopUp('" + ID.text + "');`

Comment: @Learner answered your question, just try that and let me know if it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, this should work

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "script1", "SampleJSFunction('" + vls_variable.Text+ "');", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

generally I would use a hidden parameter and access it from javascript and C# like this

ASP.NET

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenFieldID" />
```

javascript

```
var FieldName= document.getElementById('<%=HiddenFieldID.ClientID%>').value;
```

and C#

```
var x = HiddenFieldID.Value
```

note that hidden fields have string as their value,. I prefer this way so that code is easier to maintain in the future.