# Is there anyway passing variable from C# to javascript "dynamically"?

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to send a variable from C# to Javascript dynamic.

I have tried the following code down below.

But the method or the variable will only read once.

How can I make it work ?

in aspx.cs

```
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        internal static string timer = "false";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public string MyMethod()
        {
            return timer;
        }
    }
```

in aspx

```
<script>
    function GetMyName()
    {
        setInterval(function() {
            dynamic xx = "<%=MyMethod()%>";
            console.log(xx);
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: why don't use ajax to get the value?

Comment: I'm not familiar to javascript, I will try ajax, thanks @Se0ng11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variable from ASP.net to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540217/passing-variable-from-asp-net-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a property for your MyMethod()

```
protected string MyMethod { get { return timer; } }
```

Then in JS

```
<script>
function GetMyName()
{
    setInterval(function() {
        dynamic xx = "<%=MyMethod%>";
        console.log(xx);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: error in     dynamic xx = "<%=MyMethod%>";
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier