# How do i get the ID of asp.net element by javascript from javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have some script in javascript file call myjavascript.js and I want to get the content of asp:Label on my page. inside the head of my page i have linked the javascript file to the page. but am not able to reference the asp:Label om my page in myjavascript.js file. please help
below is my code

```
//on my HTML page
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="myjavascript.js"></script>
</head>

//in the myjavascript.js file
var totalamounttopay = document.getElementById('<%=Me.lblfinalgrosstotal.ClientID%>').innerText;
```

Comment: That's because `myjavascript.js` is sent as-is to the client and therefore asp.net never replaces the `<%` tag content. To make server-side data available to the client, you can either put it in an inline script or `fetch()` it from the client-side JS. The first way is very simple: insert `<script>const theID = "<%=Me.lblfinalgrosstotal.ClientID%>";</script>` above your existing script tag, then use `theID` in your script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing variable from ASP.net to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540217/passing-variable-from-asp-net-to-javascript)

Comment: can u please demonstrate with the example I gave?